# Exclamation mark on first page instead of title page when compiling document, how to fix it?

Tags: errors, compiling, standalone

When I am compiling my main.tex, I have an exclamation mark on the first page of my document (instead of my titlepage). I am using the standalone class and overleaf.
I did not have this problem before, how to fix it?

See below a picture how it looks and a MWE:

[image]

A MWE similar to my current set-up:

`Main.tex:`

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\newgeometry{left=3cm,bottom=0.1cm}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}% bibliography management package. [round] (default) round parenthesis setting
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{0, 0, 108}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue1,urlcolor=blue1,citecolor=blue1,anchorcolor=blue1]{hyperref}%

\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage[labelformat=parens,labelsep=quad,skip=3pt,font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{multirow}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\title{MWE}
\author{}
\date{\today}

\newcommand{\imsize}{0.32\linewidth}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage

\input{Results}

\end{document}
```

`Results.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\newgeometry{left=3cm,bottom=0.1cm}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}% bibliography management package. [round] (default) round parenthesis setting
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{0, 0, 108}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue1,urlcolor=blue1,citecolor=blue1,anchorcolor=blue1]{hyperref}%

\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage[labelformat=parens,labelsep=quad,skip=3ptm, font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\section*{Results}


\end{document}
```

The error:
[image]

Final Edit: MWE was sufficient enough to quickly detect the problem. `\usepackage[labelformat=parens,labelsep=quad,skip=3ptm, font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{caption}` was causing it, as `skip=3ptm` should simply be `skip=3pt`. Fixed

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal, yet complete, code reproducing the problem?

Comment: @Bernard That is going to be quite complicated. My project is quite big with multiple standalone files. I believe the error has to do with my preamble in my main.tex. Would it help if I post my preamble? Perhaps is it easy to spot mistakes in the preamble?

Comment: I would say the preamble , plus `\begin{document}\maketitle \end{document}` (check first if this is enough to reproduce the problem).

Comment: @Bernard Done, added the preamble plus ```\begin{document}\maketitle \end{document}```

Comment: @Bernard added what I believe is the source of the error.

Comment: @Leon You should try to reproduce the error with a minimal number of packages, and a minimal amount of code. It is your job to prepare a minimal working example, before asking others for help. Thanks. (Very often, doing so will make the error so obvious that you won't need help anymore, by the way.)

Comment: @frougon I provided a MWE.

Comment: @Leon The question is getting bigger and bigger, but I don't see any **minimal** working example, sorry.

Comment: Two separate files (with two `\begin{document}`) is not a MWE.  I don't see any `!`, so I don't understand why you're expecting that after your title page.  The error message you're showing us is unrelated to everything else.

Comment: @Teepeemm The seperate files are related, since I use ```standalone``` to import file to the other. @frougon the devil is in the details and one of the packages in the ```results.tex``` is causing the issue. You are asking me to provide an example with only the two packages that are causing the issue? If I would know which ones that would be, I wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: @Leon Remove packages one by one until the set of “culprits” is isolated. Every time you remove a package, compile and check. If you know what it is, you can use dichotomy to go a bit faster. Note: multiple notifications with @ don't work.